# Gallery problem in pressing back button android

Tags: android, image-gallery

Hie team gud eve, I had a set of images like 1 2 3 4 5 6. on clicking on 1 (i.e first image) the one should show in another activity. When we swipe with the finger it should move to the next image. If i stop swiping near the image position 4. while pressing the back button on the device. The main Activity should show near the position of 4.

I already done with the swipe with the help of onFling(). The problem is when i press the back button the image is moving to the first position.I need in the same position......

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
manually you can override that key  
i think this code will help u...

@Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            try {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    //start the what activity you want
    }
    }
```

Comment: @siva... i had done with this. When  close the application its directly closing my application

Comment: @siva... i had done with this. When  i press the back button application its directly closing my application

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Android 2.0 or newer, you can use `onBackPressed()` to decide what happens when you hit the back button. This is slighlty easier to do.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do something
}
```

To select a item in the Gallery:

```
gallery.setSelection(int selection);
```

Comment: Thanks.... But as i explained in the above section that it should show the same position of the  image.....

Comment: Well, you can just add some code to set the selection of your gallery. Check the updated answer to see how you can do that.